# Excel function to create a complex data base look up

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My data set has more than 10 columns and many rows and the second column text is the one I want the rest of the columns and a few rows must be linked to.

So basically the second columns can be considered as text and this text consist of a few components which is data in rows and columns that I want linked to the text.

So I want to type the text in a new sheet and be able to extract all of the data linked to the text in the new sheet under the same columns headers as it was in the data set.

Is this possible and what function or vba code would I need to use to achieve this. As I can’t find something similar anywhere.

Comment: Sounds a bit like VLOOKUP() but a screenshot would help here.

Comment: or advanced filter will also do this.

Answer (score -1):

This link might be useful for you. Try to combine examples 9 and 10 for your needs:

https://best-excel-tutorial.com/58-excel-functions/79-vlookup

Alternatively please provide more details or spreadsheet with dummy data. Will try to adjust the VLOOKUP formula for your needs.

Comment: The core part of your answer should be stated in your answer and not rely on a link staying active. It would be great if you could update your answer to contain the pertinent information.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/1N5fqgZR1ISyNBYaZeX5sXoMQ8OxRyzqO/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel

Here is the link to the data. So basically I want to type in the destination sheet under the name column the same name that corresponds to the name sheet in the data sheet and it should fill in all the cells to the right with the data that is under the name heading. For example I want to type in the destination sheet under name “cab 500” then it should fill in c2 to L 6 with the same corresponding data as under data sheet in those same cells.